# Is there a way to get Xcode's debugger to show dates in local timezone (i.e., not UTC)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, timezone, nsdate

I'm trying to debug code that makes pretty heavy use of dates which has me comparing tons of different [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) values in the debugger. The debugger is displaying those dates in UTC format--for example:

`date1 = (NSDate *) 0x01b11460 @"2012-02-15 18:55:00 +0000"`

It would be a lot easier for me if it would show them in my local [timezone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/) as that is what the test code I'm debugging seems to be using.

I do have feeling that I'm missing something much more basic here so I'm hoping someone can enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, what worked best was in fact adding a Category for NSDate that just overrides the `description` method to return a string that represents the NSDate in my current timezone. I also made it DEBUG only as I really just need this override in place when debugging.

Here's the .h file I used:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

@interface NSDate (DebugHelper)

-(NSString *)description;

@end

#endif
```

and the .m file:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

#import "NSDate+DebugHelper.h"

@implementation NSDate (DebugHelper)

-(NSString *) description
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
}

@end

#endif
```

Thanks to Jim Hayes and jrturton for the discussion and ideas that led to this answer.

Comment: Consider putting this in `-(NSString*)debugDescription`. That is what the debugger will attempt to print (default implementation just calls `description`). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379633/nsobject-description-and-debugdescription

Answer (score 1):

While a little "hackish" you can create a subclass of NSDate and override just the

```
-(NSString *)description;
```

method to return a date formatted however you want.

The debugger isn't doing any special decoding for you, it's just calling the "description" method of the object it wants to display.  A handy trick... (Which is why all my objects publish a concise description suitable for viewing in a debugger.)

Comment: A category would be better for NSDate, otherwise you'd need to use subclasses everywhere

Comment: Except that you can't replace methods using a category, you can only add them.  Since he needs to override an existing method (description), a subclass needs to be used.  Yeah, it's not pretty (for the reason you state!) but I don't see any other way around it. :-(

Comment: Yes you can. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c) for example. Its not usually a great idea, but perfect for this situation.

Comment: Interesting. I'm new to the iOS side but is there a way to make the category only get compiled in for non-release builds? For example, wrap the whole category in whatever the iOS equivalent of '#if DEBUG' is? If so, that would seem pretty close to ideal actually. I'll investigate tonight but figured I'd chime in in the meantime in case you guys have any thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I just posted an answer (the FAQ seems to say it's better that way, I'm new on SO though so let me know if I should do it differently) that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just did the same thing, however instead of systemTimeZone I used localTimeZone (see the docs as to why it is slightly better).  Also I noticed you are alloc'ing the dateFormatter object but never releasing it which is a leak.

Here's my category method:

```
-(NSString *) description;
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];

    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale]; 
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
    return dateString;
}
```