# How to override debugDescription for NSDate objects in Swift

Tags: swift, debugging, overriding, swift-extensions

I'm trying to override the `debugDescription` property when displaying the value of `NSDate` objects in the Xcode debugger.

My extension code:

```
import Foundation

extension NSDate {
   public override var debugDescription: String {
      return "FOOFOOFOO" 
   }

   public func yeah() -> String {
      return "yeah!"
   }
}
```

I've confirmed that the file with my extension code is included in the test project targets as I'm able to call the `yeah` function and `print` it successfully in the debugger's output. However, I can't seem to get the `debugDescription` property to get used.

Note my actual goal is to do what I did in Objective-C previously (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149038/is-there-a-way-to-get-xcodes-debugger-to-show-dates-in-local-timezone-i-e-no) for details), but struggling so far with how to do it in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

the are two separate protocols in Swift

```
struct S : CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "description"
    }
    var debugDescription : String {
        return "debug description"
    }
}

let s = S()
print(s)        // description
debugPrint(s)   // debug description
```

...
thanks have to go to Leo !!!

```
import Foundation
extension NSDate: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    public override var debugDescription: String {
            return "FOO"
    }
}

debugPrint(NSDate()) // FOO
```

Comment: That works fine for me. I think my problem is more around specifically how to override `debugDescription` (or `description`) on `NSDate` objects via an `extension` method.

Comment: @GusP extensions may not contains stored properties, you may not redeclare any property in an extension. you can override the property of super class ... so, what you are trying to do is not possible. If you need some special behavior, you can still subclass NSDate and override debugDescription there.

Comment: @LeoDabus: That results in an error: "Redundant conformance of 'NSDate' to protocol 'CustomDebugStringConvertible'".

Comment: Pretty unfortunate if it's not possible. Doing the same thing in Objective-C was infinitely better than having to subclass NSDate throughout my code. I think I'd actually prefer just doing the conversions in my head than subclassing. Also, were you actually able to get Leo's code to compile successfully?

Comment: @GusP of course, what you can see in my example works for me as expected

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thanks for confirming. I get the error I mentioned above when trying that code. Will see if I can figure out why it doesn't work for me.