# iOS: Object returning *nil description* after alloc and init

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let me preface this question by saying that I believe it to be a memory management mistake on my end. I just can't seem to figure out why it is happening.

I have a viewcontroller and a model class named `Part`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Part : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *partType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name AndType:(NSString *)type;

@end
```

In the view controller I have a property set as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Part *part;
```

In the `init` function of `ViewController` I create some static arrays and create objects out of them:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    self.partList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *inputArray = @[@"Part1",
    @"Part2",
    @"Part3",
    @"Part4",
    @"Part5",
    @"Part6",
    @"Part7",
    @"Part8"];

    NSString *tempType = @"PartCategory";

    // Add dummy static data
    for (int i = 0; i < [inputArray count]; i++) {
        Part *partInput = [[Part alloc] initWithName:[inputArray objectAtIndex:i] AndType:tempType];
        //partInput.name = [inputArray objectAtIndex:i];
        //partInput.partType = tempType;
        NSLog(@"Inserting Part %@", partInput);
        [self.partList addObject:partInput];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The `NSLog` I call in that loop returns `Inserting Part *nil description*` for every part. I just can't track down what is happening here.

EDIT: Here is the `initWithName` method from `Part` that the controller uses:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name AndType:(NSString *)type {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.name = name;
        self.partType = type;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the init method of `Part`. And you should always use `if (self)` after doing `self = [super init];`.

Comment: You should still check if `self` is a valid pointer in your `-(id)init` method ;)

Comment: Show us `- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name AndType:(NSString *)type` in implementation of your Part class.

Comment: Sorry about that! I've added the `init` method as requested. Thanks for the swift replies.

Comment: Does the `Part` class override the `description` or `debugDescription` methods?

Comment: @Tim Nope. It does not override either of those.

Comment: @orbv, rename `NSString *description` to something else. You shouldnt be using `description` here. `description` is already used for printing the description of the object.

Comment: @Tim I suppose it does. I didn't even notice that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `%@` to print NSObject, it calls `debugDescription` that by default calling the `description` method of that object and your `Part` object always have `nil` description.

You better solve this by changing the `description` property name to something else, because it conflicts with the `description` method of `NSObject`.

See also: [NSObject description and debugDescription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379633/nsobject-description-and-debugdescription)

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like I made a beginner's mistake.